# How to reference Eclipse jar variable from ant build.xml?

Tags: eclipse, ant, environment-variables

I have an ant build script for a project which depends on an external jar. The location of the external jar is available in Eclipse as a variable (say, `JJ2000_LIB`, added through "Add variable" in project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries).
[image: I'm talking about variables like those]
How do I access such Eclipse library variables from ant?

Ideally I would like to be able to also run the same ant script from the command line and be able to set this variable.

I've tried `env.JJ2000_LIB` which works from the command line (if I set a environment variable), but not from within Eclipse. My `build.xml` contains:

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="jj2000_lib" value="${env.JJ2000_LIB}" />

<target>
    <javac srcdir="${src}" classpath="${jj2000_lib}" destdir="${build}" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you want to add a jar to your project you need to: click with right of mouse "add to build path" (almost the same that you did).

then in the build you have to put something like this:

```
<property name="External" value="youJar.jar" />
<jar destfile="${jar.completePath}" manifest="${basedir}/manifest">
<fileset dir="${path}/classes" excludes="**/*.bak" />
<zipfileset src="${path}/${Eternal}" />
</jar>
```

Obviously you need to set the right path. It works for me.

edit: the in the manifest you should put a line like this:
Class-path: youJar.jar

EDIT:

classhpath variables (the one you define) seems to be incompatible with ant and to be used in ant (I found some bug posts in eclipse developer forum, but no one fixed). So it seems there's no way to use a classpath variable. I tried few hours to find a solution for you, now the best thing I can do for you is link this site:

http://www.ant4eclipse.org

maybe that's the solution.

Comment: But I don't want to hard code the path to my jar file. I already have such a `<property />`, except I'm using `value="${env.VARIABLE_NAME}"`, which is, like I said, working if I call ant from the command line, but I would like it to work for the "Add Variable" build path components available in Eclipse.

Comment: in that case you can create a little class that write the var into a file, compile it, run it, then read the var compile e write the jar. If is this that you need I will edit my answer.

Comment: Let me clarify my question first.